# Burninate "ukraineaid" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Should we burninate the tag [ukraineaid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukraineaid)?

It is currently applied to only 1 (one) question:
[Has the west debated the pros and cons of funding Ukraine war aid with the Russian funds they have confisticated?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/83427/28554)

There are no other tags of the form `<country>aid`. What has Ukraine done to make it so special?

Besides, the tag has a typo (missing dash).

These old tags cover the area well: [foreign-aid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-aid) and [humanitarian-aid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanitarian-aid).

All in all, burnination FTW!

Comment: Just retag the Q. New but unused tags get auto-deleted IIRC. Actually, I've just removed the tag from the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Timur in that I don't find `ukraine-aid` or similar tags useful. One can search for combinations of tags [like so](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-aid+ukraine). Thus, I don't see the need to create such tag combinations as new tags, anymore than `usa-elections` etc. are useful as tags (and for the latter topic there are [far more](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states+election) Qs.)

Somewhat aside, sometimes I did run into the max-5-tags per Q [limitation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405446/why-is-maximum-number-of-tags-on-a-question-set-to-5), but the solution to that is surely not to manually generate combo tags.

BTW, unused tags [get](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92056/shouldnt-so-unused-tags-be-deleted) automatically deleted form the system, after a while (unless someone manually creates tag synonyms for them). So it's enough to remove bad, new tags from Qs. Unless the algorithms have been tweaked since [that info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194213/why-are-there-so-many-unused-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1) was publicized (about 10 years ago), it takes around 24hrs for an unused tag to get automatically purged.

Comment: Thank you for the well-reasoned and well-researched reply! I learned from it how to deal not just with this, but with many other one-question, not very useful tags. I did not know previously about automatic removal of certain tags - this is a great feature!

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily *burninate*, but at least consider the structuring of tags.

There are [35 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bukraine%5D+is%3Aq+aid) tagged [ukraine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukraine) containing "aid".

Only [11 of those questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bukraine%5D+is%3Aq+aid+%5Bforeign-aid%5D) also use the tag [foreign-aid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-aid).

Of the remaining [24 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bukraine%5D+is%3Aq+aid+-%5Bforeign-aid%5D), some, but not all, could use an "aid" tag.

The question then is to require only the [foreign-aid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-aid) tag, or add one or more subsidiary tags for *particular* "aid" questions, such as for Ukraine, Palestine, Gaza, etc., or generalize those particular tags into the also recently added [humanitarian-aid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanitarian-aid) tag, each to stand in place of the [foreign-aid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-aid) tag.

There are 46 questions tagged [foreign-aid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-aid). There are, undoubtedly, more questions that should have that tag.

Options for tag structure are:

```
foreign-aid
  ukraine-aid
  palestine-aid
  gaza-aid
  etc.
```

or

```
foreign-aid
  humanitarian-aid
  military-aid
```

or

```
foreign-aid
```

I have no preference in any case.

Comment: I agree, I see no reason to burninate for a single question when a simple retag of that question would fix the issue.

Comment: I vote against tags such as `ukraine-aid`, `palestine-aid`, `gaza-aid`. I vote for `foreign-aid`--> { `humanitarian-aid`, `military-aid` }.